# Error #1064 near "REFERENCES" while adding a foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, alter-table

I keep getting error 1064 while trying to create a foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE `zajimavost`
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_zaj_bod 
    FOREIGN KEY def_bod
      REFERENCES `bod`(`gid`)
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

It complains:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REFERENCES `bod`(`gid`)
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE' at line 4
```

I tried it with or without the backticks, the problem is always the same.

My tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `zajimavost` (
 `zaj_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `lok_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `nazev` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci NOT NULL,
 `kategorie` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `datace_od` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '31',
 `datace_do` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '60',
 `def_bod` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`zaj_id`),
 KEY `ck_zaj_lok` (`lok_id`),
 KEY `zaj_id` (`zaj_id`),
 KEY `FK_zaj_kat` (`kategorie`),
 KEY `FK_zaj_bod` (`def_bod`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_zaj_kat` FOREIGN KEY (`kategorie`) REFERENCES `kategorie` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_zaj_lok` FOREIGN KEY (`lok_id`) REFERENCES `lokalita` (`lok_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_czech_ci

CREATE TABLE `bod` (
 `gid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `geom` point DEFAULT NULL,
 `radius` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '50',
 PRIMARY KEY (`gid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=30 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_czech_ci
```

There are data in the tables.

So how to solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `()` in child table column name while adding foreign key, Try this one

```
ALTER TABLE zajimavost 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_zaj_bod 
FOREIGN KEY (def_bod) REFERENCES `bod`(`gid`)  
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```